# ctags error with mac

Tags: macos, ctags

I have exuberant tags in my mac. Since, yesterday i am getting this error
ctags: illegal option -- R
usage: ctags [-BFadtuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...

I have followed the steps mentoned in this 
After following the steps mentioned here i can run ctags -R from command line(iterm)
But when i execute the same command from a .sh (i have a shell script where i run the cscope and ctags command using it) file i get the above error again but not when i run ctags -R from iterm directly.

Any pointers on solving this issue will be really helpfull.
Thanks in advance

Comment: okay so, i have been able to execute the correct ctags. It seems that /usr/bin/ctags is always getting executed inplace of /usr/local/bin/ctags. I did set alias ctags='/usr/local/bin/ctags' inside my bash_profile. So, now when i run ctags from command line there is no error, but when i execute which ctags it still shows /usr/bin/ctags and when i run ctags -R from a shell script it is still executing /usr/bin/ctags

Comment: `brew link ctags` could probably fix your problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, the above issue seems to be fixed. The issue being that inside the `~/.bash_profile` `PATH` variable should be set correctly. Even though my `PATH` variable was pointing to `/usr/local/bin` but `/usr/bin` appeared ahead of `/usr/local/bin` , hence somehow the ctags (when run from shell script) was picking up `/usr/bin` and not `/usr/local/bin` (which i have set alias to). Just move `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` and it worked fine.

**Solution**
Type this in terminal:
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 5):

Along with Neil answer you can simply add `alias ctags='/usr/local/bin/ctags'` to your .bashrc file.

Comment: And ```brew info ctags``` shows the path of brew intalled ctags